# How to intercept/evaluate a shell command, run logic on the command and potentially kill the command

Tags: bash, zsh

There is a command line tool at my company that many people will use, but we need to set some restrictions on the tool's usage based on the environment that the user is in.

For example, if the user is logged into our production environment and they run `dbt run <some more flags>`, I need to flash a warning and prompt them to continue or exit.

I use `zsh` myself and found the `preexec()` hook, but unfortunately, because of the way this is implemented, calling `exit` kills the whole shell and closes the terminal. This seems to be a non-starter for this option.

I'm looking for a pure `bash` alternative (many of my coworkers may not use `zsh`) that will allow me to evaluate a command before it's executed, run the command through some logic, and allow me to either kill the command or run it.

Here is the `zsh` function i wrote for reference:

```
preexec() {
  command=$1
  first_seven_chars=${command:0:7}

  if [[ "$first_seven_chars" != "dbt run" ]]; then return; fi

  if [[ "$AWS_ENVIRONMENT" != "production" ]]; then return; fi

  if [[ "$AWS_ENVIRONMENT" = "production" ]]; then 
    read -k1 -s "key?WARNING: You are in Production. Do you want to continue? Enter y to continue or any key to exit"
    
    if [[ "$key" = "y" ]]; then
      echo "Continuing in Production..."
      
      BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
      if [[ "$BRANCH" != "master" ]]; then
        echo 'You are currently not on the master branch. To prevent models and data deviating, please merge your changes into master and rerun';
        exit;
      fi
    else
      echo "\n"
      echo "\nStopping command from running in production..."
      exit;
    fi
    exit;
  fi 
}
```

Note: I realize https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec exists, but since it mirrors the `zsh` functionality it might not be the best to use.

Comment: Can you not just create an alias to dbt that runs your own bespoke script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a wrapper around the original command, not mess with `preexec` and other shell-specific hooks. Of course, you can write this wrapper itself as a zsh script. So you'll create, e.g., `dbt_safe.zsh` which would internally call `dbt`, and your colleagues would just use `dbt_safe.zsh`.